# I want to split the text and extract the cities from that text and input them into the specific city location in the data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, split

I am working on a column address of the csv file, which consists multiple country, city, pincode in a row of a .csv file, row data looks like this :

| address |
| --- |
| [Obaid, Shamsan S.; Gaikwad, Dhammajyot K.; Pawar, Pravina P.] Dr Babasaheb Ambedkar Marathwada Univ, Dept Phys, Aurangabad 431004, Maharashtra, India |
| [Kaveeshwar, Aditya Rajeev; Zappi, Mark E.; Subramaniam, Ramalingam] Univ Louisiana Lafayette, Dept Chem Engn, 218 D Madison Hall,131 Rex St,POB 42291, Lafayette, LA 70504 USA; [Ponnusamy, Senthil Kumar] SSN Coll Engn, Dept Chem Engn, Madras 603110, Tamil Nadu, India; [Revellame, Emmanuel D.] Univ Louisiana Lafayette, Dept Ind Technol, POB 43636, Lafayette, LA 70504 USA; [Gang, Daniel D.] Univ Louisiana Lafayette, Dept Civil Engn, POB 42291, Lafayette, LA 70504 USA; [Revellame, Emmanuel D.; Gang, Daniel D.; Zappi, Mark E.; Subramaniam, Ramalingam] Univ Louisiana Lafayette, Energy Inst Louisiana, POB 42291, Lafayette, LA 70504 USA |

Sample dataset:

| address |
| --- |
| [Sharma,Ravi; kumar, Ram;Pandey,Neeraj]Univeristy name1,department name1,address1, pincode **city1**, Country1; Univeristy name2,department name2,address2, pincode **city2**, Country2 ; Univeristy name3,department name3,address3, pincode **city3**, Country3 |
| [Oberai,Pia;Singh, Reshu] Univeristy name1,department name1,address1, pincode **city1**, Country1; Univeristy name2,department name2,address2, pincode **city2**, Country2 |

dataset I want as output :

| Cityname1 | Cityname2 | Cityname3 | Cityname4 | Cityname5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| city1 | city2 | city3 |  |  |
| city | city |  |  |  |

where cityname1,2,3,4,5 are just column name

My Solution that I tried to apply for solving this is :

```
import pandas as pd
rawdata = pd.csv("Filepath")
newdata = pd.DataFrame(rawdata['address'].str.rsplit(",", n=3, expand=True))
newdata
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kKLk.png)

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: [Include your minimal data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard) as part of the example.

Comment: I hope @ Prune it is okay now

Comment: Don't "hope" -- follow the guidelines to which I linked you.

Comment: Now its according to the guidelines @Prune